# In my Material-UI theme, my global override for MuiButton works, but not MuiAppBar

Tags: material-ui

Basically, I can change the colors of all Button elements in my theme, but I've been unable to do the same for AppBar. I'm puzzled. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        background: 'blue',
      },
      label: {
        color: 'white',
      }
    },
    MuiAppBar: {
      root: {
        background: 'white'
      }
    },
```

I've tried a lot of different variations on that, but nothing works. Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to the color prop in AppBar overriding your custom styling. By default, your .MuiAppBar-root class styling is being applied as expected, but the .MuiAppBar-colorPrimary class is setting the background-color to the default theme primary color. This differs from MuiButton which has the color prop set to "default" if you don't explicitly set it. If you change this to 'inherit' or 'default', the custom color should work for you.

```js
export default function CustomAppBar() {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiAppBar: {
        root: {
          background: "white"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
       <AppBar color="default">
          ...
       </AppBar>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Resources:

- https://material-ui.com/api/button/
- https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/